# Can we go beyond $1 - $9 positional parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Is there any way to use more than the `$1` to `$9` positional parameters with mod_rewrite? `${10}` does not work.

Comment: I have actually decided that pretty URLs are not the way to go. I think there is something fundamentally flawed when the way PHP scripts natively work needs to be changed because of the requirements of search engines. I think it should be the search engines that should start indexing the $_GET parameters in the script's URL.

Answer (score 0):

In apache's [RewriteRule backreference definition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) it says:

> **RewriteRule backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions.

However, you might be able to match some of the URI in a RewriteCond and use the %N backreferences, I've never tried it myself but maybe something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /ok_wow?a=%1&b=%2&c=%3&d=%4&e=%5&f=%6&g=%7&h=%8&i=%9&j=$1&k=$2&l=$3&m=$4&n=$5&o=$6p=$7&q=$8&r=$9 [R]
```

(yeah, that's pretty absurd, recursion is probably a better way to go if it's applicable).

Comment: In the link above: **RewriteCond backreferences**: These are backreferences of the form %N (1 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions.